# Where is the global pom.xml including all Apache Commons components' versions?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, apache-commons, parent-pom

As I'm starting to use several Apache Commons components in several of my Java projects, I'd like to add a single dependency to automatically handle the versions of these components in my Maven's `pom.xml`, *à la* Spring (e.g. `spring-boot-dependencies`, `spring-data-releasetrain`, `spring-cloud-dependencies`) & all their starters.

Unfortunately I'm unable to find such a thing, how do I do?

They have something called the *[Apache Commons Parent pom](https://commons.apache.org/commons-parent-pom.html)* but it seems like it's just a `pom.xml` dedicated to the build process of every components of the suite.

Comment: You can have your own parent pom in the project or local reposirtory or remote repository : https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

Comment: @codeMan indeed that's a possibility, but I didn't want to take down that path for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache commons are a collection of libraries that have very little in common (no pun intended). It makes no sense to import them en-masse.

Import just what you actually need.